# WUBI Ubuntu 12.04 boot, No kernel, GNU Grub, nothing works

Tags: grub2, kernel, wubi, boot-failure, windows-vista

Yesterday my Ubuntu 12.04 (Wubi) system was working completely fine. But today when I tried to boot I was brought to a GNU GRUB screen. Typing `boot` yields `no kernel specified` or something along those lines.

After going through many forums and Q/A sites and typing many lines of code into the `grub>` terminal, I have gotten nowhere. Most of what I type returns something about the kernel not being found and an I have no way of finding out my kernel version.

I am dual-booting alongside Vista and have also tried replacing `wubildr`. My `root.dsk` is also present so that is not an issue as many websites state.

Any help would be good and if more information is needed I will try and find it out.

Comment: Try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 1):

Did you update your kernel?
If so you might have a problem because the grub.cfg generated by wubi
is different from the one generated by update-grub after you update.

In the original grub.cfg generated by wubi, the root.disk will be mounted through
the loopback device and used as the root, and then the location of the kernel is specified according to this root directory.

After you update your kernel, the grub.cfg file won't do the same because update-grub won't know that you are using wubi and needs to mount root.disk.

The solution to this is to take a look at the grub.cfg file before your update (if you still have it or find it somewhere else) and update the grub.cfg manually using a liveCD.

Wubi is just for experiencing ubuntu on windows, but not for long-term usage.